# How can I prevent my unit test project from being deployed to my Azure Web App along with my ASP.NET Core website project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, github-actions

I have an ASP .NET Core website whose source code is stored in GitHub. This is automatically deployed to an Azure App Service (running on Linux) when I do a check-in to GitHub. (I set this up a while back using the Azure "wizard", but now I can't find any way to tinker with it).

Recently I added a unit test project to my solution, and when I checked that in the unit test project was deployed along with the web project - which I don't want. (Especially since the runtime host gets confused about which DLL it should run, and decides to run neither - so the website does not start!).

Is there a way to prevent the unit test project from being built or deployed? (I'm happy just to run these tests locally). I'm not even sure where to start - would I do this in GitHub, or in the Azure portal? I can't find any likely-looking knobs or levers either in GitHub or in the Azure portal.

**Update**: I've found a file that has been created in my repo in a `.github/workflows` folder. Here's the content:

```
    name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - MyApp

    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - master
      workflow_dispatch:

    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2

          - name: Set up .NET Core
            uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
            with:
              dotnet-version: '5.0.x'
              include-prerelease: true

          - name: Build with dotnet
            run: dotnet build --configuration Release

          - name: dotnet publish
            run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

          - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
            uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
            with:
              name: .net-app
              path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: build
        environment:
          name: 'Production'
          url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

        steps:
          - name: Download artifact from build job
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
            with:
              name: .net-app

          - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
            id: deploy-to-webapp
            uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
            with:
              app-name: 'My-App'
              slot-name: 'Production'
              publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_0C864EC866B247EABE271A962BE84378 }}
              package: .
```

While that's progress, I still can't see where I could modify it to prevent it from including the unit test project, because it doesn't actually reference anything directly.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the part of your pipeline which publishes your artifact?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole: That's the thing - I can't find where this stuff is stored. There's nothing I can see in Azure, and I can't see buttons or links in GitHub either.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole: AHA! I found a folder in the repo that contains a YAML file. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: OK. Next question - do your tests live under `/myapp` or somewhere else under the root?

Comment: You should only run `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish` from the actual web application folder, not from the solution folder. In that way only the necessary artifacts of the web app are generated and no need to further clean up.

Comment: @LexLi That sounds good - but do you know where I would find documentation on how to specify that in this YAML file?

Comment: You are calling shell commands via `run`, so just make sure you navigate to the right folder using `cd`.

Comment: @LexLi I assume you're referring to those `run: xxx` lines? Bear in mind that I wrote none of this YAML - it was automatically generated for me, so it's all greek to me. Anyway, I tried modifying the `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` lines to include a folder name, and I think that worked. (I can't tell exactly because my GitHub account has now run out of space and is refusing to build... :-( ).

Comment: The whole ecosystem is being widely so you can find far more resources than merely what's generated for you, and you can choose whatever you like. For me I always delete everything generated in the template and write a cross platform PowerShell script to build/test, where everything can be verified locally on any of my virtual machines, and you can consider that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

I changed:

```
run: dotnet build --configuration Release
```

...to:

```
run: dotnet build MyProject --configuration Release
```

...where `MyProject` is the name of the folder containing the website project. (`dotnet build` is run from the solution folder, and the default behavior is that it will build all projects in the solution; specifying a sub-folder name makes it build only the project(s) it finds in that folder - see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)).

Similarly, I changed:

```
run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

to:

```
run: dotnet publish MyProject -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

Thanks to @LexLi for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which worked for me is to set the [IsPublishable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#ispublishable) property on your test projects to false:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Using this, I could execute `dotnet publish`, and it did not publish my test project artefacts. It also meant I did not need to change my build process.